# Why JDK developers doesn't follow variable naming conventions somewhere?

Tags: java, coding-style, conventions

[Java Code conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) gives an instruction that constant name must be uppercase.

[Java Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) gives a definition of constant:

> A constant variable is a final variable of primitive type or type
> String that is initialized with a constant expression.

Now look, for example, class `LocalDate`. We can see variables that are not constants by definition, but named as constant (uppercase). Why?

```
public static final LocalDate MIN = LocalDate.of(Year.MIN_VALUE, 1, 1);
```

Comment: [Should a “static final Logger” be declared in UPPER-CASE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1417190/12323248), [What is the difference between constant variables and final variables in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30545594/12323248)

Comment: @akuzminykh it doesn't answer my question

Comment: Are you sure? The questions seem very similar to me and the answers talk about the same "problem". Are you specifically asking why a JDK developer has done this in this case?

Comment: @akuzminykh Yes. Both. They are cool and respectable guys, their code is kinda a role model. And their code doesn't follow this easy rule. Wether rule is oldish or they just missed? As a matter of fact Vadim Kotlov answered my question my closing it. He said that my question is opinion-based. It means that only LocalDate developers can answer)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why the specification makes a difference beween theses types of objects.

Conventions are all about excpectations. My expectation of a uppercase named object is, that it can not change. Also the literal meaning of constant is a situation or object that does not change.
Therefore I would use the uppercase naming convention for all immutable static final objects.

According to Oracle, LocalDate is an immutable date-time object that represents a date, often viewed as year-month-day. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html.

So I think it is OK to give `MIN` an uppercase name, because it matches my expectation, that it will never change.